# Why was the actor for Ned on Ghost Whisperer replaced?

Tags: character, casting, ghost-whisperer

In season 3 of *[Ghost Whisperer](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0460644/?ref_=ttfc_fc_tt)*, the character Ned (Son of Melinda's co-worker Delia Banks, originally played by [*Tyler Patrick Jones*](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1090133/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t12) was replaced by [Christoph Sanders](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm2324912/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t4).

Given that there is a very large difference visually between the two (as well as an apparent jump in age of the character), was there a casting/out of universe reason for the change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [the Wikipedia page for Christoph Sanders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christoph_Sanders):

> He took over the role of Ned, which was previously held by Tyler Patrick Jones, when **producers decided to age the character by few years in order to explore more mature storylines**.

As the source for this, the page refers to the book [***Ghost Whisperer Spirit Guide***](https://titanbooks.com/3862-ghost-whisperer-spirit-guide/) by **Kim Moses** and **Ian Sander** (Titan Books, 2008).